# Write Twitter Frequency analysis to a CSV using python

Tags: twitter

How do I write the output of my code to a csv?

Here is what I'm trying, the frequency analysis works, but I can't get the csv to write.  Pretty new to python, so I am sure that I am doing something wrong.

```html
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys

import re
import csv


filename = 'TweetsCSV_ORIGINAL.txt'  

word_list = re.split('\s+', file(filename).read().lower())
print 'Words in text:', len(word_list)

freq_dic = {}

punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]')
for word in word_list:
 word = punctuation.sub("", word)

 try:
  freq_dic[word] += 1
 except:
  freq_dic[word] = 1

print 'Unique words:', len(freq_dic)

freq_list = freq_dic.items()
freq_list.sort()
for word, freq in freq_list:
 print word, freq  

#write to CSV
res = [word, freq]
csvfile = "tweetfreq.csv"

#Assuming res is a flat list
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in res:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will append a line to the end of your CSV file.

```
with open('tweetfreq.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow([word,freq])
```